# Time Reversal Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, time-reversal-symmetry

I know that [time reversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry) operator is an [antiunitary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator).
How does it work on wavefunctions?
I believe in this way:
$$T \psi (k,+)=e^{i\pi S_y/\hbar} K \psi (k,+) = \psi^*(-k,-),$$ 
but I am not sure. ("+" and "-" represent spin-up or spin-down states)
Does anybody have a good explanation?

Comment: Replace $h\rightarrow \hbar$ in your formula.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Reference](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/9697/timerev.pdf) (page $13$, formula $17.71$)

The time-reversal operator is $\Theta = Ke^{-i\pi S_y/\hbar}$, where $K$ is the complex conjugation operator.

Taking a spin $1/2$, we have a wavefunction which is a $2$- component spinor $\psi(x) =  \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_+(x) \\
\psi_-(x)
\end{pmatrix}$,

Note that, for spin $1/2$, $e^{-i\pi S_y/\hbar} = e^{-i \large \frac{\pi}{2} \sigma_y} = -i\sigma_y =\begin{pmatrix}
0&&-1 \\
1&&0
\end{pmatrix}$

So time-reversal gives: $\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_+(x) \\
\psi_-(x)
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow  K\begin{pmatrix}
0&&-1 \\
1&&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_+(x) \\
\psi_-(x)
\end{pmatrix} =  K\begin{pmatrix}
-\psi_-(x) \\
\psi_+(x)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-\psi^*_-(x) \\
\psi^*_+(x)
\end{pmatrix}$

By using Fourier transform $\psi(k) \sim \int  \psi(x) e^{ -i k.x}$, we may notice that the Fourier transform of $\psi^*(x)$ is $\psi^*(-k)$. So we get the time-reversal operation:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_+(k) \\
\psi_-(k)
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
-\psi^*_-(-k) \\
\psi^*_+(-k)
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: The reference is inaccessible now.

Comment: The step going from $e^{−i\frac{\pi}{2}\sigma_y}=−i\sigma_y$ is described [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/510221/matrix-exponentiation-of-pauli-matrix)

Comment: This is generally wrong. Time-reversal operator can take all kind of forms and depends on the Hamiltonian